# How to get Sequelize validation error informaiton?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

If I have a model that should validate, but does not (because Sequelize throws)... what is the validation that fails? All I get is `SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error`

Thanks.

Comment: you can try the follwoing link https://www.npmjs.com/package/validatorjs

Comment: Thank you, but Sequalize already has validation... this is only adding a layer on top of an existing feature; it's redundant. Besides, I already have client-side validation, thus why my "[the] model should validate, but does not".

Comment: Can you post code of your model moreover there must be a unique key on the column which is being provided with duplicate entries.